# std::visit template with overloaded functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit and I can't understand the template example (#4) in the code sample:

```
// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

// 4. another type-matching visitor: a class with 3 overloaded operator()'s
        // Note: The `(auto arg)` template operator() will bind to `int` and `long`
        //       in this case, but in its absence the `(double arg)` operator()
        //       *will also* bind to `int` and `long` because both are implicitly
        //       convertible to double. When using this form, care has to be taken
        //       that implicit conversions are handled correctly.
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
        }, v);
```

Can someone explain to me what `operator()` is the text referring to and how are three lambda function types passed as 'base classes' (: Ts) for that struct?
I really don't get it

Comment: It's referring to the `operator()` of the lambda expressions

Comment: The first line creates a single class which derives from all classes given by Ts. As this, all operator(), independet of their signature, will be part of that class. The second line tells the compiler to create that class by only giving the constructor parms ( user defined deduction guide ). The visit now simply passes an instance of the class which contains all operator(). As we now have an overload, the correct one will be used.